# ExpressionEngine textarea increase limit

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

Scenario:

- Client adds newsletters to his website
- `textarea` field cuts off the pasted source code at a particular character count.
- Looking at increasing the character count limit for the `textarea` so that the entire newsletter source code can be pasted.
- Using ExpressionEngine 2.5.2

Any thoughts on how to increase the MySQL character limitations? I looked through the `channel_fields` and tried increasing the row count from 172 to 9999 and the `field_settings row` to `longtext`, but this had no effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just tested this and the way around this issue is to alter the structure of the `exp_chanel_data` table itself.

Using PHPMyAdmin, Sequel Pro, or similar, alter the structure of `exp_channel_data` by changing the data type from `TEXT` to `MEDIUMTEXT` on the field that corresponds to your custom field.  The field name  will be something like `field_id_x` where X corresponds to the  id of the custom field field you are working with.

Comment: don't forget to make a backup before proceeding just in case.

Comment: That's exactly what it was, we weren't looking that the field itself. Thanks again!